# specific word or one word for using social websites while working

Tags: single-word-requests

Kindly help, I am looking for specific word for using too much facebook/twitter/linkedin etc while working.

Comment: Does that include using stackexchange too much?

Answer (score 4):

A single word is ***"goldbricking"*** which has a rich history (per [WorldWideWords.org](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-gol2.htm)), beginning as a specific event where someone was swindled using a brick that was supposed to be gold but was mostly not...to it's current meaning which is to "goof off", or in other words, someone who is not doing their job.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider, [***cyberloafing***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cyberloafing&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccyberloafing%3B%2Cc0)

> The use of computers by employees for purposes unrelated to work.
>
> Etymology: cyber- +‎ loafing (Wiktionary)
>
> [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cyberloafing)

Answer (score 1):

Someone who isn't putting in 100% effort could be said to be **[slacking](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20slacking)**:

> `BRITISH` *informal*
>
> work slowly or lazily.

Answer (score 0):

If a person is using social networking sites during work, it could be an **addiction**, although most times, the site is a **distraction**.

Comment: This answer looks interesting; could you add some dictionary definitions of your words, so people know specifically what meanings you're driving at? Please mention which dictionary you're quoting.